# Wrong resources fetched

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, asp.net, resource-files

I am working on a SharePoint project and we have an Arabic version and an english version.
There are two ways of changing languages. Either switch SharePoint platform language, or sending the language in query string: `language=ar-SA` or `language=en-US`.
However in a page of the pages, the query string method is not working. (It is written in extjs and asp where others are HTML5-JS):

```
<ext:Button runat="server" ID="BtnClear" Icon="Decline" Text="<%$Resources:ESDigitalSignatureResources, Clear_Button %>">
```

It is always fetching the SharePoint language.

Here is the C# code that is handling the query string

```
public bool IsArabicCulture
{
    get
    {
        int lcid = 0;
        if (Request.QueryString["language"] != null)
        {
            string language = Request.QueryString["language"];
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
            lcid = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language).LCID;
        }
        return (lcid == 1025 || System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID == 1025);
    }
}
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (this.IsArabicCulture)
    {
        this.ViewPort.RTL = true;
    }
}
```

I am counting on `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` to change the language.
I've tried moving it from `Page_Load` to `OnLoad` then to `OnInit` with no luck.

Comment: When you say "in a page of the pages" do you mean that it's working correctly on all pages *except* this one?

Comment: yes but the other pages are using javascript (the javascript file is sent by code)

Comment: Also just for clarification, what version of SP is this? 2010/2013/O365/etc...

Comment: It is 2013 I forgot to put it